# postfix & dspam "Daemon mode failed to start "

Tags: postfix, dovecot, dspam

I'm experiencing this issue on my postfix/dspam/dovecot configuration:

```
May 28 12:35:59 mx01 dspam[1514]: Creating local domain socket /var/spool/postf
ix/dspam/dspam.sock
May 28 12:35:59 mx01 dspam[1514]: Daemon mode failed to start
May 28 12:35:59 mx01 dspam[1514]: Daemon process exiting
```

This is my /etc/postfix/master.cf:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -        smtpd
  -o content_filter=lmtp:inet:127.0.0.1:10024
#127.0.0.1:10024      inet  n       -       n       -       -        smtpd
# DSPAM
127.0.0.1:10024 inet n  -       n       -        -      smtpd
        -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
#dspam-retrain   unix    -       n       n       -       10      pipe
  #flags=Ru user=dspam argv=/etc/dspam/dspam-retrain $nexthop $sender $recipient
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
```

Any idea?

Comment: This error can be caused by many factor. Is dspam user has permission to create socket in `/var/spool/postfix`? Is dspam has enough memory to start?

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you [edit] the question and postfix dspam configuration instead postfix `master.cf`

Comment: Solved. The misconfiguration was in dspam.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The misconfiguration was in dspam.conf file, here the correct configuration:

```
Home /var/spool/dspam
#StorageDriver /usr/lib/dspam/libhash_drv.so
StorageDriver  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dspam/libhash_drv.so
TrustedDeliveryAgent "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
#DeliveryHost        127.0.0.1
#DeliveryPort        10024
#DeliveryIdent       localhost
#DeliveryProto       SMTP
DeliveryHost            /var/run/dovecot/lmtp
#DeliveryHost           /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp
DeliveryIdent           localhost
DeliveryProto           LMTP
OnFail error
Trust root
Trust dspam
Trust mail
Trust mailnull
Trust smmsp
Trust daemon
Trust postfix
Trust www-data
Trust vmail
Debug *
WebStats on
TrainingMode teft
TestConditionalTraining on
Feature chained
Feature whitelist
Algorithm graham burton
PValue graham
Preference "spamAction=tag"
Preference "signatureLocation=headers"  # 'message' or 'headers'
Preference "showFactors=off"
AllowOverride trainingMode
AllowOverride spamAction spamSubject
AllowOverride statisticalSedation
AllowOverride enableBNR
AllowOverride enableWhitelist
AllowOverride signatureLocation
AllowOverride showFactors
AllowOverride optIn optOut
AllowOverride whitelistThreshold
HashRecMax              98317
HashAutoExtend          on
HashMaxExtents          0
HashExtentSize          49157
HashMaxSeek             100
HashConnectionCache     10
Notifications   off
PurgeSignatures 14          # Stale signatures
PurgeNeutral    90          # Tokens with neutralish probabilities
PurgeUnused     90          # Unused tokens
PurgeHapaxes    30          # Tokens with less than 5 hits (hapaxes)
PurgeHits1S     15          # Tokens with only 1 spam hit
PurgeHits1I     15          # Tokens with only 1 innocent hit
LocalMX 127.0.0.1
SystemLog on
UserLog   on
Opt out
TrackSources spam ham
ParseToHeaders on
ChangeModeOnParse on
ChangeUserOnParse on
ServerPort              11124
ServerPID              /var/run/dspam/dspam.pid
ServerMode auto
ServerParameters        "--deliver=innocent -d %u"
ServerIdent             "localhost.localdomain"
ClientHost      127.0.0.1
ClientPort      11124
ProcessorBias on
Include /etc/dspam/dspam.d/
```